# gradle won't update the repositories in build.gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I added slf4j in my project and deleted one maven repo. Rebuild the project and it no longer works.

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for org.slf4j:slf4j-api.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://whatever.com/artifactory/maven/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://whatever.com/artifactory/maven/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

build.gradle

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs("libs")
        }
    }
}
```

`maven { "whatever.com" }` used to be there but is not anymore. But gradle is trying to pull sfl4j from that repo. I tried:

- Invalidate caches/restart
- Remove build folder
- Remove .idea folder
- Remove ~/.gradle/caches
- Clean project
- Close Android Studio all together and build it from terminal
- I made sure the build.gradle is saved correctly in the system

Why wont gradle update the repositories?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out due to the setup of my application I had to upgrade to `org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.+`. I am still unsure why was the old repository showing up in the error log.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your `~/.m2` cache next time. Maven cache is stored under this folder that might have caused issues.

[Source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.0/html/deploying_into_the_container/locate-buildtime)